# Comparison of books on the historical development of quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education, history

I am looking for a good book on the historical development of quantum mechanics. I have come across quite a few, but do not know which to read. I have a graduate background in physics, and so I am hoping for a (at least somewhat) technical review. Not a text book, but not a pop science level read. I have come across the following and would appreciate any information on how technical or mathematical the books are and your general opinion on them (especially if you could compare any of the books) or recommend other I have not listed.

Books I am interested in:

- *Quantum: Einstein, Bohr and the Great Debate About the Nature of Reality* by Manjit Kumar
- *The Conceptual Development of Quantum Mechanics* by Max Jammer
- *Quantum Generations: A History of Physics in the Twentieth Century* by Helge Kragh

Other books I've come across but are not what I'm looking for:

- *The Historical Development of Quantum Theory* multivolume series by Mehra and Rechenberg

  - This seems like a wonderful read, but very long
- *The Old Quantum Theory* by Ter Haar

  - I plan to read this eventually
- *Letters on Wave Mechanics: Correspondence with H. A. Lorentz, Max Planck, and Erwin Schrödinger*

I know there are many collections of the actual source material as well as biographies of individual quantum physicists, but those are not what I am looking for at the moment.

Comment: The following might be something to add to your list:  "Sources of Quantum Mechanics" by B.L. van der Waerden.  I believe this covers material that includes some of the background from 1900-1925 for context as well as the developments 1925- when Heisenberg formalized things.  It includes some technical commentary tying these periods together, along with original papers from many of the main contributors.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Try asking also here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67358/book-recommendations-on-science and maybe here https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: van der Waerden is indeed a good read.

Comment: Go for Jammer. Old enough to still be close to that period and the bibliography covers all relevant papers from the founding fathers.

Comment: yes Jammer is nice although it's very linear historically and some it does feel old in the way the material is presented (and typeset).  However it remains a fantastic and unrivalled source, especially for quasi-forgotten references and actors that history seems to have forgotten.